# Making my first request to an API with a token using python 3.6

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and working on learning data science. I have recently been trying to make my first API request using the urllib package and requests module but have so far failed abjectly.

The documentation from the website states that I should code the following in python in order to access the API:

```
curl  https://soccer.sportmonks.com/api/v2.0
   -H "Accept: application/json"
   -X GET
   -d
       '{
           "api_token" : "your-token"
        }'
```

I have tried the following using the urllib package without success:

```
 import urllib.request
 import urllib.parse
 url = 'https://soccer.sportmonks.com/api/v2.0'
 values = {'H' : "Accept: application/json", 'X' : 'GET', 'api_token' : 
          'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'}

 data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
 data = data.encode('ascii')
 req = urllib.request.Request(url, data)
 response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

This code throws up all sorts of errors, the latest one being: urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error

I know my failure stems from the way I'm calling the API, so what am I doing wrong? What am I not doing that should be done?

Using the requests module, I've tried the following:

```
  import requests

  response = requests.get(url, values) # both arguments inside the function 
  are defined above
```

This again throws up all sorts of errors. What am I not doing right?

Any help much will greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requests allows you to specify the headers and data as separate key word arguments,

`response = requests.get(
        url, 
        headers={'Accept': 'application/json'}, 
        data={'api_token' : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'}
)`

This matches your curl request, however you may want to consider adding the api token to your headers as well. Not how you use python dictionaries and not strings as the input arguments.

Side note requests is a fantastic library that provides an easier api to urllib3 and I would recommend using it unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: Do I have to authenticate myself before calling the api to extract data?

Comment: These requests will occur in isolation so it has to contain all authentication. In this case it is contained in the data key word. Sorry about the belated reply.